# Nuxt - different scrollToTop behaviour depending on which page you come from

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a 'page' that contains router links to the same page, but with different parameters. I know about the scrollToTop attribute that you can use to determine whether upon entering said page, the page will start in top scroll position.

However, in my case, I would like different scrolling behavior depending on where you come from.
I'd like the scrollToTop to not be triggered if you enter the page by a link from the page itself.

[image: pages]

So lets say the page in question is one.vue and one.vue contains router links to one.vue itself, with different parameters. If I click a router link on one.vue, that links to one.vue, I'd like to **not** scrollToTop, but in all other cases I do want to scrollToTop. How would I achieve such a feat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve it by using the router.scrollBehavior property inside nuxt.config.js. The following will scrollToTop except if your are to and from are this same specific page.

```
scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
  if (to.name === 'index-Product-id-productname' && from.name === 'index-Product-id-productname') return
  return { x: 0, y: 0 }
},
```